# building AOSP for my tablet

Tags: android-source

I am trying to build AOSP for my tablet. I have the 4.4.2 source code of my device and I am downloading 5.1.1r1 AOSP source code from google. Can anyone please explain me what are the steps to follow to build AOSP for my device? Is there any tutorial to do that? Please let me know.

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: @MagnusBäck Lenovo Tab-2 A7-10

Comment: Rebuilding 4.4.2 using the vendor sources and proprietary binaries would just barely be a beginner project.  Porting generic 5.1.1 having only a vendor 4.4.2 as a guide (and probably having no 5.1.1 version of various binary helpers the vendor doesn't provide in source form) is not something you want to tackle without experience under your belt.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : I am ready for the challenge. DO you have any tutorial or anything for that? I have drivers of that vendor. you can check Lenovo website. They open sources it.

Comment: This is precisely what is wrong with your question: you are told that it will be difficult to do pioneering work.  You respond that you are ready for the challenge.  And then you ask for a tutorial?   If you want step-by-step, you will probably have to stick with trying to rebuild 4.4.2 (or whatever the latest version the Vendor has published for your device) as a learning project, or finding/waiting until someone has ported a custom ROM to your device.

Comment: I wanted to have the generic way of porting ROM. There must be a generic framework/way of porting a ROM. ie. adding drivers or UI change, or may be adding something additional from vendor and deleting. Then at deeper level there will be changing drivers for specific device, changing UI for specific device, stripping of feature which are not valid for that device.

Comment: That is a overall view, that is what I precisely wanted to know. And there might be several other things which I don't know. This is what my requirement is. If you have the answer you are welcome otherwise please do not show this kind of attitude :) It's of no use for anyone of us

Answer (score 3):

You need to port you product configuration within `device/<your_vendor>/<your_device>` and the proprietary vendor binaries, which are hardware specific, to your new software stack. Also you need the kernel for your devices. The kernel and the vendor binaries can be extracted from your device.

The product configuration contains e.g. build flags, files to copy to the resulting images, the `init.rc` files and the information what should be built.

The proprietary vendor blobs are mostly the [HAL](https://source.android.com/devices/#Hardware%20Abstraction%20Layer) layer implementations for your hardware.

For more information on how to do that and what you need to consider, please see my other answers here on stackoverflow: [Build for another Android Version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35246750/2327227) and [Building Vanilla AOSP Rom with CM repos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35103228/2327227).

Answer (score 1):

### install required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev libc6-dev lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z1-dev libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc uboot-mkimage openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-jre vim-common
```

### step 1. setup enviornment

```
source build/envsetup.sh
```

### step 2. select board and build configuration

```
lunch 

export TARGET_PRODUCT=pandaboard   
//you need to select target device name
```

or we can give

```
lunch target-device-name
```

for example: `lunch pandaboard`

### step 3. setup toolchain

```
export TARGET_TOOLS_PREFIX=android-toolchain-eabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-  //have to give toolchain path
```

### step 4. compilation

```
make -j8
```