# Samsung Open Source for Android, its usage?

Tags: android, build, samsung-mobile, android-6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy

I downloaded android device open source from Samsung OSRC.

It was composed with Platform.tar.gz and Kernel.tar.gz

It seems to do with building AOSP, found mk files.

I'm curious whether it can be used(directly or indirectly) to build newer android version for device and whether I have to build new kernel based on this files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build for a newer Android version, you do not need to build another kernel. Just use the kernel provided by Samsung for your device (or the prebuilt kernel from your phone).

When porting a device to a newer Android version you need to adjust the init configuration (`init.rc` files from your product configuration located in `device/<vendor>/<your_device>`), but not the kernel specific parts of your `init.rc` files.

You also need to add the hardware specific vendor binaries to your resulting flash image. Therefore you can extract these libraries from your device. Most of them are located in `/system/vendor/lib`, but there could be also some libraries in `/system/lib` and all subdirectories.

It is also possible that some vendor binaries does not work within another software stack. Possible reasons are incompatible [HAL](https://source.android.com/devices/#Hardware%20Abstraction%20Layer) interfaces and incompatible libraries. The solution for these cases can be very different and should be evaluated individually.

If you are facing such issues you can have a look at the [CyanogenMod](https://github.com/CyanogenMod) sources for a hint. There you can find lots of ports. Best place to look is the product configuration of the particular device. You can also look into another of my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35103228/2327227) regarding this topic.